# How to pass propss in RTK useLazyQuery() hook to generate data based on dynamic URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I want to render component based on props. These props will also have to pass with useLazyQuery() hook to generate dynamic URL and view data. If I pass only credentials, the generated data is fine. But when I am trying to add props with it, always generates error.

What to do ? Please help.

My Base Query Slice :

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
    credentials: 'include',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const token = getState().auth.accessToken
        if (token) {
            headers.set('authorization', `Bearer~${token}`)
        }
        return headers
    }
})
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery,
    endpoints: builder => ({})
})
```

My Injected Query Slice :

```
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";

//Dynamic URL based on props
const leaveApplViewUrlGen = nature => {
    switch (nature) {
        case 'apr': return '/hr/leave/application/apr'
        case 'can': return '/hr/leave/application/can'
    }
}
const leaveApplViewUrlSelf = nature => {
    switch (nature) {
        case 'apr': return '/hr/leave/application/self/apr'
        case 'can': return '/hr/leave/application/self/can'
    }
}

export const leaveApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    tagTypes: ['Appl'],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        leaveApplView: builder.query({
    // Problem generating through here
    // I want to generate dynamic URL based on props value
            query: ({credentials, self, nature}) => ({
                url: self
                    ? leaveApplViewUrlSelf(nature)
                    : leaveApplViewUrlGen(nature),
                method: 'POST',
                body: { ...credentials }
            }),
        }),
    })
})

export const {
    useLazyLeaveApplViewQuery
} = leaveApiSlice
```

My Complnent:

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
    import Select from 'react-select'
    import {
        useLazyLeaveApplViewQuery
    } from "../../../features/hr/leaveApiSlice"
    
        // Component loading based on props
    const LeaveAppl = ({ self, nature }) => {
    
        const projectCodes = [
            { value: '84', label: '84' }
        ]
        const reportYears = [
            { value: '2022', label: '2022' }
        ]
        const reportMonths = [
            { value: '03', label: 'MAR' }
        ]
    
        const [projectCode, setProjectCode] = useState(projectCodes[0].value)
        const [reportYear, setReportYear] = useState(reportYears[0].value)
        const [reportMonth, setReportMonth] = useState(reportMonths[0].value)
        const employeeCode = ''
    
        const [applTrigger, applData] = useLazyLeaveApplViewQuery()
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setProjectCode(projectCodes[0].value)
            setReportYear(reportYears[0].value)
            setReportMonth(reportMonths[0].value)
        }, [self, nature])
    
        const refreshLeave = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
    
            const applCredentials = self
                ? { projectCode, reportYear, reportMonth }
                : { projectCode, reportYear, reportMonth, employeeCode }
    
            try {
        // Problem generating from here
        // I want to generate dynamic URL based on props value
                await applTrigger(
                    { applCredentials, self, nature }).unwrap()
                if (applData.isSuccess && applData.data) {
                    console.log(applData.data)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                if (!err?.originalStatus) {
                    console.err('Processing Error!');
                }
            }
        }
    
        return (
            <section className='leave-appl'>
                <form>
                    <Select options={projectCodes}
                        onChange={e => setProjectCode(e.value)}
                    />
                    <Select options={reportYears}
                        onChange={e => setReportYear(e.value)}
                    />
                    <Select options={reportMonths}
                        onChange={e => setReportMonth(e.value)}
                    />
                    <button type='button' onClick={refreshLeave}
                    >Refresh</button>
                </form>
            </section>
        )
    }

export default LeaveAppl
```

Comment: It might help if you share the text of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
Pass it like this:-

```
await applTrigger({ ...credentials, self, nature }).unwrap()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You pass them in as args in your function call, exactly as you are already doing:

```js
applTrigger({ applCredentials, self, nature })
```

This is correct code. As you are not sharing the error message, it's not really possible to give any feedback on that.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. The error code is 403, forbidden. self & nature automatically added with payload.
{
"applCredentials":{
    "projectCode": "84",
    "reportYear": "2022",
    "reportMonth": "09",
    "employeeCode": "",
    "applicationNumber": "0"
},
"self":"false",
"nature":"pre"
}
The back end log is shown like this
[projectCode=null, reportYear=null, reportMonth=null, employeeCode=null, applicationNumber=0]
In stead of this
[projectCode='84', reportYear='2022', reportMonth='09', employeeCode=, applicationNumber=0]